# Constructing an object of unique values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators

I am looking though the code at

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022

and this code

```
// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});
```

looks strange to me. I understand what the code is supposed to do (it is supposed to build a list of objects called "nodes" with the unique values of link.source and link.target), but I do not understand the construct. Please explain how the statement above works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this
`link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});`

You have to notice the parens. 
On first iteration
As the result of `(nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});` the system will output `{name: 'Microsoft'}`
And  this output will be assigned as value of `links[0].source`

Conclusion, not only it construct nodes object as you said. It also change the structure of items inside links object, become:

```
var links = [
    {source: { name: "Microsoft"},
```

Same is true for `target`

lemme know if its still hard to grasp

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this modifies links too. So the array being iterated on is being changed in-place during iteration. I have heard that this is bad practice (in Python context), is it acceptable for JS?

Comment: it is common to modify variables in js. Since js variables stays in your browser until you close the page, it would be resource demanding to clone every variable passed to a function, because js is pass by reference language you need to do extra step to clone it. Of course this is true before introduction of `let` and `const`. But if you use react for example, you take this into consideration, but in vanilla js i dont face problem caused by mutating variables often

Answer (score 1):

I take only the first line of the callback. The second line works as the first line.

First of all, it is an assignment.

```
link.source =
```

with the following expression which has two parts,

```
              nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source})
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

where the first part is evaluated and if the result is falsy, the second part is evaluated.

The advantage of this approach is to prevent a new assignment to `nodes[link.source]` with

```
               nodes[link.source] = nodes[link.source] || {name: link.source}

link.source = (nodes[link.source] = nodes[link.source] || {name: link.source})
```

and now the version with an explicit check

```
if (!nodes[link.source]) {
    nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source};
}
link.source = nodes[link.source];
```

Comment: Thanks! The explicit check version really clarifies things.